# Download several files from a local server to a client

Tags: python, python-2.7, networking

The following codes let me download from server to client three files called *tmp.bsp*, *tmp.seq* and *tmp.dms*. However, just the first file *tmp.dms* is completely downloaded. The other one *tmp.seq* is filled up with the informations of *tmp.bsp* and *tmp.bsp* stay 0KB.

**client:**

```
import socket 

import socket 

skClient = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
skClient.connect(("127.0.0.1",2525))

sData = "Temp"
sData2 = "Temp"
sData3 = "Temp"

while True:
    sData = skClient.recv(1024)
    fDownloadFile = open("tmp.dms","wb")

    sData2 = skClient.recv(1024)
    fDownloadFile2 = open("tmp.seq","wb")

    sData3 = skClient.recv(1024)
    fDownloadFile3 = open("tmp.bsp","wb")

    while sData:

        fDownloadFile.write(sData)
        sData = skClient.recv(1024)
        fDownloadFile.close()

        fDownloadFile2.write(sData2)
        sData2 = skClient.recv(1024)
        fDownloadFile2.close()

        fDownloadFile3.write(sData3)
        sData3 = skClient.recv(1024)
        fDownloadFile3.close()

    print "Download over"
    break

skClient.close()
```

`n` is a counter and the prints are for debugging.
`sFileName` is to download one file, and used to work but since I want three files I just commented it.

**server:**

```
import socket

host = ''
skServer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
skServer.bind((host,2525))
skServer.listen(10)
print "Server currently active"

while True:
    Content,Address = skServer.accept()
    print Address
    files = "C:\Users\Name_user\Desktop\Networking\Send_Receive/"
    fUploadFile = open(files+str('tmp.dms'),"rb")
    sRead = fUploadFile.read(1024)

    fUploadFile2 = open(files+str('tmp.seq'),"rb")
    sRead2 = fUploadFile2.read(1024)

    fUploadFile3 = open(files+str('tmp.bsp'),"rb")
    sRead3 = fUploadFile3.read(1024)

    while sRead:
        Content.send(sRead)
        sRead = fUploadFile.read(1024)

        Content.send(sRead2)
        sRead2 = fUploadFile2.read(1024)

#       Content.send(sRead3)   
#       sRead3 = fUploadFile3.read(1024)

    Content.close()
    print "Sending is over"
    break


skServer.close()
```

**files I'm using:**
[server2.py is my server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8soD.png)
[Execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t32Pp.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue with your code is that you're sending / receiving an arbitrary number of data. If your buffer (1024) is smaller than the file size then the client's file will contain less information, and if it's larger the file may contain more information (data from the next file).

You could solve this issue by sending a value that signifies the end of a file. The problem with this method is that this value can't be contained in any file, and the client must be scanning the received data for this value.

Another possible solution is to calculate the file size and send that infomation in front of the file data. This way the cilent will know how many data to expect for each file.

Using [`struct.pack`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.pack) we can create a minimal four bytes header with the file size.

```
def send_file(soc, path):
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        data = f.read()
    size = struct.pack('!I', len(data))
    soc.send(size + data)
```

Tthen the client can get the file size by reading four bytes and [`unpack`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.unpack)ing to int.

```
def recv_file(soc, path):
    size_header = soc.recv(4)
    size = struct.unpack('!I', size_header)[0]
    data = soc.recv(size)
    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(data)
```

Note that sending/receiving files with one call may raise a socket error if the file size is larger than the socket buffer. In that case you'll have to read the data in smaller chunks in a loop, or increase the buffer size with [`socket.setsockopt`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.setsockopt).

Here is a modified version of the above functions that can handle large files:

```
import struct
import os.path

def send_file(soc, path):
    file_size = os.path.getsize(path)
    size_header = struct.pack('!Q', file_size)
    soc.send(size_header)
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        while True:
            data = f.read(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            soc.send(data)

def recv_file(soc, path):
    size_header = soc.recv(8)
    file_size = struct.unpack('!Q', size_header)[0]
    chunks = [1024 for i in range(file_size / 1024)]
    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in chunks:
            f.write(soc.recv(chunk))
        f.write(soc.recv(file_size % 1024))
```

I haven't tested this code thoroughly, but it should work for files of any size.

---

An example using the `send_file` function in your server:

```
host = ''
skServer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
skServer.bind((host,2525))
skServer.listen(10)
print "Server currently active"

Content,Address = skServer.accept()
print Address

files = ['tmp.bsp', 'tmp.seq', 'tmp.dms']
for file in files:
    send_file(Content, file)

Content.close()
print "Sending is over"
skServer.close()
```

Using `recv_file` in the client:

```
skClient = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
skClient.connect(("127.0.0.1",2525))

files = ['tmp.bsp', 'tmp.seq', 'tmp.dms']
for file in files:
    recv_file(skClient, file)

print "Download over"
skClient.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for fixing my problem, I will be carefull with the size of my buffer because indeed I'll have to move large files.

Comment: Glad to help! If your files are larger than a fiew kb you could use a loop or set the `socket.SO_SNDBUF` and `socket.SO_RCVBUF` to a higher value with `socket.setsockopt`. If the files are so large that can't be stored in memory you'll have to use `os.path.getsize` to get  the file size.

Comment: Yeah, the files will be about several GB

Comment: I've updated the code to handle larger files. Although I haven't tested it with really big files, it should work fine.

Comment: I'll test that soon and let you know

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right, I did run your program and found exactly same issue. I dont have enough time to work more on this issue but I found few key points which might lead you to the right work around.

[https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.htmlhttps://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html)

The above official doc says:

> When a recv returns 0 bytes, it means the other side has closed (or is in the process of closing) the connection. You will not receive any more data on this connection. Ever. You may be able to send data successfully

This is what it is happening when the third file returns 0 bytes.

But why 2nd and 3rd file is merged, I guess its because sockets are just buffered files and we might need to try making sure buffer is clear before sending another.

Read this,

> Now there are two sets of verbs to use for communication. You can use send and recv, or you can transform your client socket into a file-like beast and use read and write. The latter is the way Java presents its sockets. I’m not going to talk about it here, except to warn you that you need to use flush on sockets. These are buffered “files”, and a common mistake is to write something, and then read for a reply. Without a flush in there, you may wait forever for the reply, because the request may still be in your output buffer.
>
> But if you plan to reuse your socket for further transfers, you need to realize that there is **no** EOT on a socket. I repeat: if a socket send or recv returns after handling 0 bytes, the connection has been broken. If the connection has not been broken, you may wait on a recv forever, because the socket will not tell you that there’s nothing more to read (for now). Now if you think about that a bit, you’ll come to realize a fundamental truth of sockets: messages must either be fixed length (yuck), or be delimited (shrug), or indicate how long they are (much better), or end by shutting down the connection. The choice is entirely yours, (but some ways are righter than others).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I guessed that and tried to close the connection, I even thought it was because I didn't open right my files but it didn't work anyway.
Thanks to you, now I have a lead of what might be the problem. Do you know how I can't refresh my buffer ?

Comment: even after using flush() you can't refresh buffer? I mean clear buffer!

Comment: No, it's not working in any ways :/ I can't refresh my buffer using flush

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally fluent in Python, but I think your while statement should be something like:

```
while: sData or sData2 or sData3
```

I may have the syntax wrong, but currently it looks like you will stop when "sData" is done and stop downloading sData2 and aData3 at that time even if they haven't finished.

Hmm--either that or the "While" isn't looping at all and it's just being used as an "if"?  hard to tell without knowing the API.

Comment: I know what you mean and that's a problem I'll fix later. What I need to do first is to have my three files at the end filled with the information initially in them, and I don't know why I have the file 2 and 3 mixed up

Comment: Did you intend the server files to be listed in the opposite order from the client files?  You send bmp-seq-dms but read them in the opposite order.

Comment: No, it was an edit mistake but it didn't change anything anyway. I'm still stuck and I tried to close the file after writing, it didn't work either